# loop instance method with list elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest

I am  trying to write a  program (API testing)  to loop   through  instance  methods  in a class.  One of the  methods "get_one_sale_license"  has a  variable "self.sale_sgid_in_test"  I need   to assign   this variable  each  element  in the list "sale_list_final" .The   variable  is used in the instance  method as well as  the main function. I   put a  for loop   outside   the class  and it works fine  with the  output( this  is    modified  part of  a  single  file   from the application using framework).
  However, I want   to remove  the loop wrapping the   class  and   try in a more pythonic way.

```
import json
from datetime import *
from N import NSession
from N import NArgParser
from i_data_provider import iDataProvider

sale_list = open("sales.txt").readlines()
sale_list_final = [s.rstrip() for s in sale_list]
tests_list = open("tests.txt").readlines()
tests_list_final = [t.rstrip() for t in tests_list]

cnt=0
cnt2=0
cnt3=0
cnt6=0
cnt11=0

for i  in sale_list_final:


    class iDeployChecks:

        def __init__(self, badge, environment):
            self.session = NSession(badge=badge,environment=environment)
            self.logger = self.session.logger
           # self.sale_sgid_list = []
            self.sale_sgid_in_test = ''
            self.i_session = iDataProvider(self.session)


        def get_all_saleable_sales(self):
            global cnt2
            if cnt2 == 0:
                self.i_session.get_sale_seller_info()
                self.logger.info('SUCCESS..... Get all sales api\n')
                cnt2 += 1


        def get_all_sale_dashboard(self):
            global cnt6
            if cnt6 == 0:
                self.i_session.get_All_sale()
                self.logger.info('SUCCESS..... Get all sales on dashboard api\n')
                cnt6 += 1

        def get_current_user_sale_dashboard(self):
            global cnt11
            if cnt11 == 0:
                self.i_session.get_current_user_sale()
                self.logger.info('SUCCESS..... Get current sales on dashboard api\n')
                cnt11 += 1


        def get_one_sale_license(self):

            self.logger.info('Getting sale details from:')
            self.sale_sgid_list1 = [item.get('salesgid') for item in self.i_session.get_sale_seller_info()]
            #self.sale_sgid_list =[item.get('salesgid') for item in self.i_session.get_sale_seller_info() if item.get('salesgid') == i]
            print "                           for sale " + str(i)
            self.sale_sgid_in_test = ''.join(i)
            self.logger.info('\n')
            self.logger.info('Get License for sale with sale sgid {}'.format(self.sale_sgid_in_test))
            self.i_session.get_sale_license(self.sale_sgid_in_test)
            self.logger.info('SUCCESS..... Get license api\n')

        def get_weekly_stats_count(self):
            global cnt
            if cnt == 0:
                self.i_session.get_weekly_statistics()
                self.logger.info('SUCCESS..... Weekly statistics api\n')
                cnt += 1

        def get_sconfig_value_count(self):
            self.i_session.get_sconfig_value(self.sale_sgid_in_test)
            self.logger.info('SUCCESS..... sconfig api\n')


        def main(self):
            start = datetime.utcnow()

            # check if the method  in the list  is present in the class, if yes  run it.
            for j in tests_list_final:

                k = "self." + j + "()"
                l= [x.strip() for x in j.split(',')]

                m= "self."+l[0]+"(self,year)"

                n= "self."+l[0]+"(self,year,month)"

                if k == str("self.get_all_saleable_sales()"):
                    if cnt2 == 0:
                        self.logger.info('Get All sales')
                    self.get_all_saleable_sales()


                    self.logger.info('checking if sale with GSID ' + i + ' exists')
                    if i not in str(self.i_session.get_sale_seller_info()):
                        print "the sale with GSID " + i + " does not exist !!"
                        end1 = datetime.utcnow()
                        self.logger.info('i health check completed in {} seconds.'.format((end1 - start).seconds))
                        return
                    else:
                        print "sale exists !!"


                    continue

                elif k == str("self.get_one_sale_license()"):

                    self.get_one_sale_license()
                    continue

                elif k == str("self.get_sale_node_status_value()"):
                    try:
                        self.logger.info('Get sale node status for  sale sgid {}'.format(self.sale_sgid_in_test))
                        self.get_sale_node_status_value()
                    except Exception as e: print e

                else:
                    global cnt3
                    if (cnt3==0):
                        print '\n'
                        print "  The testcase " +k + "test does not exist,please recheck test name !!"
                        print '\n'
                        cnt3 +=1
            end = datetime.utcnow()
            self.logger.info('IBDL health check completed in {} seconds.'.format((end - start).seconds))




    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = NArgParser(description='i Checks')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        iDeployChecks(args.badge, args.environment).main()
```

Comment: Why are you defining a class inside a loop? O_o

Comment: that  is  what I   want to get  rid of

Comment: Do you even use the variable i inside the loop? Do you need the loop?

Comment: yes print "                           for sale " + str(i)
            self.sale_sgid_in_test = ''.join(i)  in get_one_sale_license(self)

Comment: self.sale_sgid_in_test = ''.join(i)     is used   in one method   which   is  then used in other methods and the   main function too. I want to  eliminate the  loop. The  code  works   but  I think this   is  not the  right way to do  this

Comment: What is in the value i? Could you just store that value as a variable inside the class and access it that way? instead of using i and a loop?

Comment: strings -alpha  numeric  like  'ABCD522XX', okay  let me try

Comment: why don't you turn this `i` into a parameter of `iDeployChecks.__init__()` (which will store it as a private attribute), then simply iterate with `for i in sale_list_final: iDeployChecks(args.badge, args.environment, i).main()` ?

Comment: Thanks AK47  and Guillaume , that  works  !!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the   loop  and  include in the **init**

```
def __init__(self, badge, environment):
     self.session = NSession(badge=badge,environment=environment)
     self.logger = self.session.logger
     self.sale_sgid_list = [i for i in sale_list_final]
     self.sale_sgid_in_test = ''
     self.i_session = iDataProvider(self.session)
```

Then loop for the  same list element while calling the  main

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = NArgParser(description='i Checks')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    for i in sale_sgid_list:
       iDeployChecks(args.badge, args.environment,i).main()
```